# Angular 6, request httpClient (type errors)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have errors in my services. I'm trying to grab a list of medias (which was created by NodeJS, and that launches a JSON with all media). I can recover it but I have a "Property 'medias' error does not exist on the type 'Media []'".

Here is my service

```
getMedias(): Observable<Media[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Media[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/media')
      .map(mediasFetched => mediasFetched.medias);    <strong><!> L'erreur est juste ici <!></strong>
  }
```

My component where I get the media:

```
this.mediaService.getMedias().subscribe(mediasFetched => {
      this.medias = mediasFetched;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
```

If I do not add ".medias" to "mediasFetched" I only get an object that contains my table. I have to go through this property to get my table and that's where my mistake is.

I have to go through this property to browse it with a ngFor in my html.

Excuse me in advance if I miss a big thing, but I start with Angular: p

Thank you

Comment: can you post your media.ts file code here

Comment: add this medias: any[] or medias:string acc to your req

Comment: @yer My model ? export interface Media {
  id: number;
  m_title: string;
  m_duration: number;
  m_year: Date;
  m_country: string;
  m_season: number;
  m_order: number;
  m_fk_id_type_media: number;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your model, try adding this medias: any[]

```
export interface Media { 
   medias: any[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, with <{medias: Media[]}>, remove the observable and add subscribe on my service.

Service:

```
getMedias() {

    this.http
      .get<{ medias: Media[] }>(`${this.apiUrl}media`)
      .subscribe(mediasData => {
        this.medias = mediasData.medias;
        this.mediasUpdated.next([...this.medias]);
      });
  }
```

component.ts:

this.mediaService.getMedias();

@yer Thank you for your alternative